# acton page with below php mysql form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have small php mysql form  with below code. both form and processing code on same page and its working fine too. But i want to use action in form tag, so that form can move to another page. and when i add  than form is moving to b.php after click submit button but than its not submitting data into database. is there any way i can submit data and move to another page after clicking submit.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

                $url='localhost';
                $username='root';
                $password='';
                $conn=mysqli_connect($url,$username,$password,"hrm");
          if(!$conn){
          die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysqli_error());
          }
          $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          $handle = fopen($file, "r");
          $c = 0;
          $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
          while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
                    {
          $empid = $filesop[0];
          $empname = $filesop[1];
        
          $sql = "insert into tmmach (empid, empname) 

        values ('$empid','$empname')";
          $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

         $c = $c + 1;
           }

            if($sql){
               echo "sucess";
             } 
         else
         {
            echo "Sorry! Unable to impo.";
          }

}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  role="form">              
        <label>File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150"  class="form-control" required>
        <p class="help-block">Only CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the form action to b.php and move the code which processes the form into b.php

Comment: @ASyson yes sir its conventional way, i done this before,  but is there anyway without moving processing code to b.php ???

Comment: Yes you could do a redirect to b.php after you've finished processing it